# append extension to anchor href containing DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, anchor

I'm trying to append a file extension to an href for a link which contains a `@Html.DisplayFor` with a file extension following it an example would be:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/images/@Html.DisplayFor(m => element.name)<text>.png</text>">Image Link</a>
```

I found that in regular HTML I could use `<text>` but in this case the markup is invalid.

The image that the links point to are dynamically generated i.e. are not static files on the server.

I could concatenate the file extension to the name in the controller before sending it to the view but I would prefer if there is a way of doing it in the View.

Comment: `DisplayFor` can be localized - shouldn't you just put the file name on your model?

Comment: `<a href="@string.Format("http://www.example.com/images/{0}.png", Model.name)">Image Link</a>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that solves it. Thanks.